# javascript validate value against array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking for a way to verify against an array.
I'm lost in the array searching part.

I may get an array like this:

```
stream = ["apple","orange", "grape", "peach","strawberry","watermelon", "kiwi", "raspberry"];
```

But I only want :

```
selection = ["apple", "peach","strawberry","kiwi", "raspberry"];
```

How would I write a statement that would say:
If something in this stream matches my selection, do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the inArray command like this:

```
if($.inArray(ValueToCheck, YourArray) > -1) { alert("Value exists"); }
```

InArray will search your array for the value you asked for and return its index. If the value isn't present, it returns -1.

Comment: +1 should be `inArray()` but otherwise yes, that's what I would use

Comment: @BrokenGlass - Thanks for reminding me, I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var stream    = ["apple","orange", "grape", "peach","strawberry","watermelon", "kiwi", "raspberry"],
    selection = ["apple", "peach","strawberry","kiwi", "raspberry"];

stream.forEach(function(elem) {
    if( selection.indexOf(elem) > -1 ) {
        // we have a match, do something.
    }
});
```

Note that [`Array.prototype.forEach`<sup>help</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`.indexOf()`<sup>help</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) are part of Javascript 1.6 and may not be supported by any InternetExplorer < version 9. See **MDC**'s documentation on alternative versions.

There are lots of other ways to accomplish the same thing (using a "normal" `for-loop` for instance) but I figured this is probably the best trade-of in performans vs. readability.

Anyway, all the used Javascript 1.6 functions are actually very trivial to write on your own.

jQuerys [`$.inArray()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will also use `Array.prototype.indexOf()` if it's supported by the browser.